# upconvolution implementation: where do the implementation come and effect of upsampling

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

People implement the upconvolution in different ways. Basically one is to do fractional strided convolution, and the other is first upsampling the image and then do convolution. I saw the first one in implemntation of [FCN](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn8s/net.py#L68) and UNet, however I haven't seen the second one in any official implementation of published paper. Wonder if anyone can point to an example of using the second approach in official source code of publication?

Also, in the second approach, the upsampling function can have different behavior (say bilinear, linear, etc.) but authors of paper usually just say "upconvolution/upsampling". How to determine which kind of upsampling to use (except for trying each one to see the final result)? Or, it does not really matter? (didn't find paper on this topic)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the application of upconvolution or say transpose-convolution(this is more accurate) is quite broad, involving visualization/pixel-wise
prediction/unsupervised learning/image generation.

More specifically:

（1）unsupervised learning: traditional convolution operation is to get feature maps from original images, tran-conv could help find kernel and feature map through unsupervised learning to rebuild images. Like convolutional sparse coding described in [1],[2].

（2）CNN visualization[3]：by restoring the feature maps learned from CNN-conv to pixel map, we can figure out what kind of pattern could activate these feature maps.

（3）upsampling[4][5]：like you said in FCN and U-Net, max-pooling operation shrink the size of images therefore, we need to do upsampling which could also be done by trans-conv. The difference is that train-conv is learnable upsampling. The parameters could be learned during the training process.

Since padding is always the first step of trans-conv, there are different kinds of padding methods now which could lead to different de-conv methods.

[1] Zeiler M D, Krishnan D, Taylor G W, etal. Deconvolutional networks[C]. Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, 2010.

[2] Zeiler M D, Taylor G W, Fergus R, etal. Adaptive deconvolutional networks for mid and high level featurelearning[C]. International Conference on Computer Vision, 2011.

[3] Zeiler M D, Fergus R. Visualizing andUnderstanding Convolutional Networks[C]. European Conference on ComputerVision, 2013.

[4] Long J, Shelhamer E, Darrell T, et al.Fully convolutional networks for semantic segmentation[C]. Computer Vision andPattern Recognition, 2015.

[5] Unsupervised Representation Learning with Deep Convolutional Generative Adversarial Networks

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer almost answers everything
I would just like to add that, it does really matter whether you use interpolation or transposed-conv for upsampling

In FCN, We need to use Bilinear interpolation. Infact, I tried to use transposed-conv[initialized with 0 or random] thinking it ll give us better result because it is sophisticated but it did not work.
I had to then initialize the weights of my filter[trans-conv] with bilinear interpolation to make FCN work

In case of U-nets, this would fail as it requires learnable weights and we can not fix them and do interpolation